How to get MiKTeX to install a package from a style file on Windows
For many of my TeX documents, I am using a .sty file which I found online and modified to adapt it to my use (originally, it was Evan Chen's evan.sty). For the first few projects, I just copied the file into that folder, but I figured I should probably figure out where to put it to avoid doing that in every file...
After some digging around, and as the different commands I found online to find the root folder didn't work, it seems that all the different packages were in folders in user\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex, so I tried to put the .sty file directly in that folder, and tried creating a folder with my package name, both (unsurprisingly) didn't work.
Then, I tried installing it with MiKTeX, and creating a nex texmf tree. I created a mytexmf/tex/latex/package_name/package_name.sty path in a folder completely oustide of MiKTeX, and then added mytexmf to the roots on MiKTeX. However, when I tried selecting a "local  package repository" as the source for adding packages, and selected mytexmf, it showed me an error message (see picture). It showed the same message when I tried all the subsequent folders in the path, as well as when i tried selecting the folder with all of the package files.

How do I install the package, either on MiKTeX or otherwise? Is there an easy way of doing that of making tha folder a 'local package repository'? I tried following the instructions on this post, but it didn't work.
Thank you for any and all help.

Step 1:
Open MiKTeX Console and go to Settings > Directories.
Step 2:
Click the ADD buttom (a plus symbol) to add a folder (custom TEXMF). In my example the folder is located in E:\mytexmf.

Step 3:
Your folder should have the following structure:

generic > images is for media I want to use globally (I store some logos and branded images to avoid making a copy of that in every project
latex is for packages. Each package has its own folder and in each folder there is a .sty file. (tblr-extras folder has a tblr-extras.sty inside, among other files)
Step 4:
Update the filename database as shown in the following image:

Step 5:
Profit?. Upvote and mark as accepted if this answer helped.
